# Getting class/method name that called a common function

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio-2010, logging, typeof

I'm not quite sure how best ask this question, so please feel free to edit...

I have a  "Utilities" class that contains common functionality used throughout my application. One of my methods logs exeptions like this:

```
internal static void logExeption(Type typeOfClass, string methodName, Exception exeption )
 {
   //Do some logging here
 }
```

Then I'd like to call it throughout my application whenever I catch an exception like so:

```
try{
  //perform some action
}
catch(Exception ex)
{
Utils.logExeption(this.GetType(), System.Reflection.MethodBase.GetCurrentMethod().Name, ex);
 }
```

I would like to know if there's a way I can avoid passing in the first two parameters and just figure out the context of the Class/Method where the exception originated right in the **logException** method. This will make things cleaner for me in the long run.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

So you want to determine the calling object and the function. Though it is not recommended it can be achieved. Use System.Diagnostics.StackTrace to walk the stack; then get the appropriate StackFrame one level up. Then determine which method was the caller by using GetMethod() on that StackFrame. Note that building a stack trace is a potentially expensive operation, and it's possible for callers of your method to obscure where things are really coming from.

```
StackFrame frame = new StackFrame(1);
MethodBase method = frame.GetMethod();
string message = String.Format("{0}.{1} : {2}",
method.DeclaringType.FullName, method.Name, message);
Console.WriteLine(message);
```

Answer (score 2):

Please note that `frame.GetMethod().DeclaringType` can return `null`: sometime ago I faced with this problem only on **release build** of my application using [NLog logger](http://nlog-project.org/) (`GetCurrentClassLogger`). Can't remember exactly the case. By the way, it is [known issue](http://nlog.codeplex.com/workitem/6999).

There is an interesting trick in [Apache log4net](http://logging.apache.org/log4net/) which allows to detect the caller info (class, method, etc.).

Please take a look at:

1. `LocationInfo` class ([source](https://github.com/apache/logging-log4net/blob/master/src/Core/LocationInfo.cs)) - the internal representation of caller location information.

   ```
    public class LocationInfo
    {
        ...

        public LocationInfo(Type callerStackBoundaryDeclaringType)
        {
            // Here is the trick. See the implementation details here.
        }

        ...
    }
   ```
2. `LogImpl` class ([source](https://github.com/apache/logging-log4net/blob/master/src/Core/LogImpl.cs)) - the logger implementation class - wrapper around ILogger interface - to do the trick **it must not be subclassed**!

   ```
    public class LogImpl : LoggerWrapperImpl, ILog
    {
        ...
        public LogImpl(ILogger logger) : base(logger)
        {
            ...
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// The fully qualified name of this declaring type not the type of any subclass.
        /// </summary>
        private readonly static Type ThisDeclaringType = typeof(LogImpl);

        virtual public void Error(object message, Exception exception)
        {
            Logger.Log(ThisDeclaringType, m_levelError, message, exception);
        }

        ...
    }
   ```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [StackTrace Class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/System.Diagnostics.StackTrace.aspx). See the example there which is very similar with your question.